# Backbone and Node Js , how to switch different views?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, mongodb, backbone.js

I'm working on an application using backbone.js, node js ,express and mongodb. 
A model, collection and view have been created for one of my entities. In this case product.
Using .fetch function I can call my web api and retrieve all my elements in a collectionView successfully.

server.js:

```
app.get( '/api/products', function( request, response ) {
    var regex = new RegExp(request.query.searchWord, 'i');  // 'i' makes it case insensitive
    return ProductModel.find().or([{ 'title': { $regex: regex }}, { 'description': { $regex:     regex }}]).exec( function( err, products) {
    if( !err ) {
        console.log("Server sending products...");
        console.log(adds);
        return response.send( products);
    } else {
        return console.log( err );
    }
});
});
```

At client side I have a collection called ProductList a CollectionView, a model called Product and a ProductView (Backbone).

In my client side, backbone's collection view:

```
var app = app || {};
app.ProductListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#productsDiv',
    self: this,
    initialize: function(  ) {
        this.collection = new app.ProductList();
        this.collection.fetch({ data: $.param({ searchWord: ""}), reset: true});
```

This returns correctly the collection consuming api url and I can display it correctly.

At this point I have created a second model called User and need it to display its view on screen clicking on a link at the top of my page. No postback should be done. It should be Single-Page application.

Do I need to use a Router to call my server.js on node.js "api/user" url and fetch this data?

Which is the best approach to switch different views using node.js and backbone? Any suggestion?

Thank you in advance.